# which is the best way to write javascript ForEach

Tags: javascript

I heard forEach require a function that get 3 parameter, what about style 4 where parameters defined it. Why it's can work?

```
let arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

//1
function temp(value, index, arr) {
    console.log(value);
}

arr.forEach(temp);

//2
arr.forEach(function(value, index, arr) {
    console.log(value);
});

//3 
arr.forEach((value, index, arr) => {
    console.log(value);
});


//4 
arr.forEach(e => 
{
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Because it's javascript. It doesn't check arity much.

Answer (score 0):

The function definition defines the names of some variables that any arguments will be passed to.

That is all.

It does not enforce the number of arguments that can be passed.

You can pass any number of arguments to any function.

Some arguments might be ignored.

```js
function myFunction(a, b, c) {
  console.log("My function with " + arguments.length + " arguments");
  console.log(a, b, c);
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log("Argument " + i + " is " + arguments[i]);
  }
}

myFunction(100);
myFunction(200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700);

function myFunctionWhichChecks(a, b, c) {
  if (arguments.length !== 3) {
    throw new Error("myFunctionWhichChecks must have exactly 3 arguments");
  }
  console.log("My function which checks has " + arguments.length + " arguments");


}

myFunctionWhichChecks(800, 900, 1000);
myFunctionWhichChecks(800, 900, 1000, 1100);
```